# Postgresql, for each userid in table loop insert x times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out how to insert x amount of times from a WITH table.
I want to insert one coupon for every ticket they got.
What I want to do is following:

```
WITH tic AS (
   SELECT userid,
        sum(price * ticketamount) AS total_price,
        sum(ticketamount) As amount_of_tickets
   FROM piljetter_system.soldtickets tic
   WHERE consertid = 7
   GROUP BY userid
)
UPDATE piljetter_system.users usr
   SET pesetas = pesetas + tic.total_price
FROM tic
WHERE usr.userid = tic.userid;
```

For each userId in tic do the insert below times amount_of_tickets. Like a loop for each userid do insert x times.

```
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons (tic.userid)
```

Every coupon will get a unique number as default.

I'm thankful for what you can help me with.

Edit: Is this something I can do with generate_series()?

Comment: This seems like something to write a procedure for, using a cursor and for loop instead of a WITH statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
WITH tic AS (
      SELECT userid,
             sum(price * ticketamount) AS total_price,
             sum(ticketamount) As amount_of_tickets
      FROM piljetter_system.soldtickets tic
      WHERE consertid = 7
      GROUP BY userid
    )
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons c ( . . . )
   SELECT . . .   -- whatever columns you want
   FROM tic CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        generate_series(1, tic.amount_of_tickets) gs(n);
```

Comment: I like the way you think, but I dont get it to work. What I want to do is to INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons (tic.userid) as many times as the amount_of_tickets the userid have over at tic.

Comment: @Ludvig . . . I fixed the answer.  I was clearly confused by your use of `update`, when `insert` seems to be what you want.

Comment: @Ludvig . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Didnt know about it, must have been a misstake.

Answer (score 0):

To insert using `WITH` is simple:

```
WITH tic AS (
    SELECT userid,
    sum(price * ticketamount) AS total_price,
    sum(ticketamount) As amount_of_tickets
       FROM piljetter_system.soldtickets tic
       WHERE consertid = 7
       GROUP BY userid
)  
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons(tic.userid)
SELECT userid FROM tic;
```

`WITH` creates a temporal table named *tic* using the query inside `AS()`. This temp table tic is abailable for the next query that in this case is an insert.

SQL allows the insertion of records that is why is posible to do:

```
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons(tic.userid)
SELECT userid FROM tic;
```

Where you insert the records from the table *tic*.

The insertion is in the order of the table, if you want to insert in a certain order you can add that order in the query:

```
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons(tic.userid)
SELECT userid FROM tic ORDER BY total_price DESC;
```

The insertion depends on the table piljetter_system.coupons if it has a primary key with autoincrement (serial), then the ID will be generated automatically.

You can use `WITH` with multiple iterations. So if you want to insert the updated rows you can concatenate with your update like this:

```
WITH tic AS (
   SELECT userid,
        sum(price * ticketamount) AS total_price,
        sum(ticketamount) As amount_of_tickets
   FROM piljetter_system.soldtickets tic
   WHERE consertid = 7
   GROUP BY userid
),updated_tics (
UPDATE piljetter_system.users usr
   SET pesetas = pesetas + tic.total_price
FROM tic
WHERE usr.userid = tic.userid
RETURNING usr.userid)
INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons(tic.userid)
SELECT userid FROM updated_tics;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I mixed your two answers together to be able to do what I wanted. Here is my complete version that works for me.

```
WITH tic AS (
   SELECT userid,
        sum(price * ticketamount) AS total_price,
        sum(ticketamount) As amount_of_tickets
   FROM piljetter_system.soldtickets tic
   WHERE consertid = consertidi
   GROUP BY userid
),updated_tics AS (
UPDATE piljetter_system.users usr
   SET pesetas = pesetas + tic.total_price
    FROM tic
    WHERE usr.userid = tic.userid
RETURNING usr.userid, tic.amount_of_tickets)
    INSERT INTO piljetter_system.coupons (userid)
   SELECT updated_tics.userid
   FROM updated_tics CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        generate_series(1, updated_tics.amount_of_tickets) gs(n);
```